# Why is slapd logging "connection_read(12): no connection!"?

Tags: openldap

Why is slapd logging "connection_read(12): no connection!" ?

This is a fresh install.
There are no other connections.
Message also logged at `olcLogLevel: none`.

**the command**

```
kldap1 ~ # ldapwhoami 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
dn:gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
```

**the log**

```
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: conn=1055 fd=12 ACCEPT from PATH=/var/run/openldap/slapd.sock (PATH=/var/run/openldap/slapd.sock)
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: conn=1055 op=0 BIND dn="" method=163
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: conn=1055 op=0 BIND authcid="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" authzid="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth"
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: conn=1055 op=0 BIND dn="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" mech=EXTERNAL sasl_ssf=0 ssf=71
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: conn=1055 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: conn=1055 op=1 EXT oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.3
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: conn=1055 op=1 WHOAMI
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: conn=1055 op=1 RESULT oid= err=0 text=
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: conn=1055 op=2 UNBIND
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: conn=1055 fd=12 closed
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: connection_read(12): no connection!
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: connection_read(12): no connection!
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: connection_read(12): no connection!
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: connection_read(12): no connection!
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: connection_read(12): no connection!
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: connection_read(12): no connection!
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: connection_read(12): no connection!
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: connection_read(12): no connection!
Jul 25 15:24:37 kldap1 slapd[6137]: connection_read(12): no connection!
```

**the config**

```
kldap1 ~ # ldapsearch -b cn=config "(|(cn=config)(olcDatabase={-1}frontend)(olcDatabase={0}config))"
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=config> with scope subtree
# filter: (|(cn=config)(olcDatabase={-1}frontend)(olcDatabase={0}config))
# requesting: ALL
#

# config
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcConfigFile: /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
olcConfigDir: /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
olcAllows: bind_v2
olcArgsFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
olcAttributeOptions: lang-
olcAuthzPolicy: none
olcConcurrency: 0
olcConnMaxPending: 100
olcConnMaxPendingAuth: 1000
olcGentleHUP: FALSE
olcIdleTimeout: 15
olcIndexSubstrIfMaxLen: 4
olcIndexSubstrIfMinLen: 2
olcIndexSubstrAnyLen: 4
olcIndexSubstrAnyStep: 2
olcIndexIntLen: 4
olcLocalSSF: 71
olcPidFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcReverseLookup: FALSE
olcSaslSecProps: noplain,noanonymous
olcSizeLimit: unlimited
olcSockbufMaxIncoming: 262143
olcSockbufMaxIncomingAuth: 16777215
olcThreads: 16
olcTimeLimit: unlimited
olcTLSCACertificatePath: /etc/ssl/certs/
olcTLSCRLCheck: none
olcTLSVerifyClient: try
olcToolThreads: 1
olcWriteTimeout: 0
olcLogLevel: stats

# {-1}frontend, config
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcFrontendConfig
olcDatabase: {-1}frontend
olcAddContentAcl: FALSE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 0
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcSchemaDN: cn=Subschema
olcSizeLimit: unlimited
olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
olcTimeLimit: unlimited
olcMonitoring: FALSE

# {0}config, config
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to *  by * none
olcAddContentAcl: TRUE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcRootDN: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
olcMonitoring: FALSE

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 4
# numEntries: 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`slapd` was started with `-h 'ldaps:// ldap:// ldapi://%2fvar%2frun%2fopenldap%2fslapd.sock cldap://'`

Inclusion **cldap://** of  causes this behavior for reasons I am not going to try to figure out right now. If anyone can answer with some clarity why this is the case, I'll change the accepted answer to ours.

Hadn't meant to answer my own question, but stumbled upon the answer and I figure why waste other people's time.